# Is it possible for a router to act as a wireless switch?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have an old router/modem/access point, thompson TG782i. There is currently a different router/modem/access point managing supplying me with Internet however I would like to expand the wifi area covered.

The thompson doesn't support repeater mode, but i was wondering could it be possible to use a purely as a access point. The wired equivalent would be just to plug a switch in a router and everything would work from start.

My question is, is this possible as a concept, what king of synchronizations should be set up between the two wireless devices (should they both have DHCP on)? And could it be that the ISP has been messing with the device to prevent theses kinds of "do it yourself" hacks?

Comment: Only the one connected to the Internet should have DHCP on. The other must have DHCP off. And make sure not to connect the WAN/Internet port to anything.

Answer (score 1):

link them both by cable.

your "AP router" will add new clients to the network and allow the other router to assign the IP's.

just make sure you add the router to the "new AP" as dns server and not itself. also make sure the "new AP" has DHCP off.

[image]

note: any IP on the picture is merely used as example.

Comment: if this is for any reason not possible to be done, poke my head with a hammer and i will remove this answer. fact is, im rusty in the LAN department.